# Delete lines from a file which opened in less mode

Tags: vi, less, deleted-files

I have a file (huge size) which cannot be opened in `vi` but in `less` mode and I want to delete the lines which I do not required. But I am unable to delete lines from file open in `less` mode.

Please suggest how can I delete lines in `less` mode

Comment: May be `sed` helps? Can you somehow indentify lines which you want to delete? By number, key-phrase, etc. ?

Comment: @Costas yes, there will be one unique account number in file and i can find the line number for the same which i need to delete

Comment: So there is not a problem to use `sed` for your task `sed --in-place 'line_number_from,line_number_till d' file`

Comment: Why can't it be opened in vi?

Comment: What is less mode? Is that a vi feature?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing would be to use `sed`.

`sed '/pattern/d' file` to delete lines containing a certain pattern.

`sed 'start_line_number,end_line_number d' file` to delete a range of lines.

Both examples above will just print the file contents to STDOUT **without modifying the contents**. If you want to modify the actual file add `-i` or `--in-place` immediately after `sed`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible

1. Open the file in less.
2. Type `vi`. The file will open in vi.
3. Press `Esc [number_of_lines] dd`, then save the file (type `:wq` to write and quit).
4. It will go back to `less` with modified content.
5. Exit

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as the OP stated that `vi` can't be used and we don't know why.

Comment: `v` invokes ${EDITOR:-vi} and, as has been pointed out, that is explicitly ruled out.